# Partially moving samba user to the new server

Tags: samba, sync

There are many questions like this one and many other good links, one of these link is: 
[Link1](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-move-migrate-user-accounts-old-to-new-server/)
But this answer is useful too:
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219170/how-to-migrate-all-users-to-an-new-server)

I must not move all of the users from the old to the new, only some of them.
I did already the part of adding the user and copying the hash password on the new server with the exception that the users got a new UID and in the /etc/shadow I only added the hash password in place of "!".

There is no way I'm able to sync the system password of the users with the samba's one.

I created a test user and I've done the same thing, but I also run the command `smbpasswd -a userTest` with the result that after setting a random password and a service restart, this user can log into its folder
(It's like I created a new samba user then.. nothing special and not even close to my goal).

But, I do not know the samba password of others and I can't even move all of them (not all and not again).

Do you know how sohuld I proceed? You'd help me a lot!

EDIT: Samba server, Ubuntu 14.04 | Clients, All Windows 7 (connected through vpn) | smb.conf is handmade and working, no need to post really

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not possible to just "convert" existing users to samba users.
I'd let them set their password with smbpasswd command

https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2011-December/165422.html